# tessedit_char_whitelistに日本語を指定する方法

Tags: powershell, tesseract

Windows11 64bit 22H2で`tesseract v5.3.3.20231005`を使っています。
powershellから`tesseract.exe`を呼び出してOCRでカタカナの`ア`など限られた文字を抽出するため、configの引数で`tessedit_char_whitelist`を指定したのですが正常に動作しません。
`tessedit_char_whitelist`で日本語などのマルチバイト文字を指定する方法があればご教示ください。

`ア`を指定するコマンド例

```
# 何も抽出できない
.\tesseract.exe hoge.png stdout -l jpn -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ア
.\tesseract.exe hoge.png stdout -l jpn -c tessedit_char_whitelist="ア" 
.\tesseract.exe hoge.png stdout -l jpn -c tessedit_char_whitelist=[char]0x30a2
# 0,2,3,a,u のみ抽出
.\tesseract.exe hoge.png stdout -l jpn -c tessedit_char_whitelist=\u30a2
.\tesseract.exe hoge.png stdout -l jpn -c tessedit_char_whitelist="\u30a2"
```

数字を指定するコマンド例

```
# うまく動作する
.\tesseract.exe hoge.png stdout -l jpn -c tessedit_char_whitelist=1234567890
```

蛇足ですが、chcpが932のコマンドプロンプトでも同様に動きませんでした。
`python 3.11.0`と`pytesseract`でも下記のコードで動作しません。

```py
with Image.open("ans.png") as image:
    # 何も抽出できない
    command = '-c tessedit_char_whitelist="ア"'
    #command = '-c tessedit_char_whitelist="\u30a2"'
    #command = '-c tessedit_char_whitelist="\\u30a2"'
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang="jpn", config=command)
    # うまく動作する
    #text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang="eng+jpn", config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist="1234567890"')
    print(text)
```

**参考にならなかった資料**

- [Whitelist for Non-English Characters #3070](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/3070)

  - "Actually i have tried with russian characters and it worked pretty well."や"把系统语言设置成utf8貌似是成功的。"(システム言語をutf8に設定すると成功したようです。)
    と書かれているのですが私の環境で解決できませんでした。(pythonのソースコードはutf-8で書いています)